# Interface and Implementation Classes

Tags: object-oriented, spring

I know various forms of this question have come up before, but none of them quite seem to answer in a way that I can apply to / understand in relation to what I regularly see others doing. Specifically, when dealing with a Spring / Springboot / Seam project, what benefit is there to having a separate implementation and interface class for a bean and having them in the same package and module?

For example, if I have (for a Seam application):

```
public interface MyRepository {}
```

and

```
@Name("myRepository")
public class MyRepositoryImpl implements MyRepository {
    //impl
}
```

wouldn't any project that can acess the MyRepository interface also already be injecting the implementation class? I'm guessing there's something I'm missing for how this helps allow for different implementations, but I've not been able to find a good explanation for the benefits in this setup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the case of repositories or other data access classes, interfaces usually exist to make testing easier. If your repository implements an interface, and your application consumes the repository as an interface rather than concrete implementation, then it is easier to isolate parts of your application that require data access. Your unit tests can mock the repository by injecting a TestMyRepository object, which implements the same interface.

So it is not really about the application using only one implementation. It allows you to create a second implementation for testing purposes. It is easy to forget that mock or stub objects are also concrete implementations. Mocks and stubs exist to facilitate testing rather than actual data access.

Answer (score 1):

> wouldn't any project that can acess the MyRepository interface also
> already be injecting the implementation class?

It helps if the interface is *not* in the same package as the implementation :D

[image]

In Figure 2 in the image above, Object B depends on the { Object A + Interface A } combo (Package A). This is called dependency inversion.

Instead of thinking of it as being the interface *of* the repository class, think of it as being an interface defined for the benefit of the *code that uses* repository (the interface is "owned" by that code, and it's in the same package as that code). The interface represents what *that* code requires other code to implement in order to provide repository services for the owning code.

Because Package A doesn't know about Package B, some 3rd peace of code that knows about both has to connect them together (e.g., your main() method).

These don't have to be packages, though, they can just be logical groupings.

In this setup, you can replace the implementation with a different one, and reuse Package A in different scenarios (maybe you're writing to a file, or to an SQL database, or in a testing scenario, maybe it's a mock).

One point that is often misunderstood is that you don't necessarily get abstraction simply by pulling out an interface; the interface (meaning the methods, their parameters and return types) have to be expressed in higher level terms compared to Object B (it can't be too specific to Object B). In fact, if you separate them into packages like this, since Package A doesn't reference Package B, nothing in that interface can be a thing that's declared in Package B. It has to (and it should be) expressed in terms of concepts that are in Package A.

Now, in many applications this often takes the form of a generic CRUD-y interface, but that has questionable value, and tends to get bloated over time as people keep adding methods to it by inertia (this is just something I found online):

```java
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
    extends Repository<T, ID> {
    <S extends T> S save(S entity);
    void delete(T entity);
    Long count();

    boolean exists(ID primaryKey);
    T findOne(ID primaryKey);
    Iterable<T> findAll();

    // … this tends to grow
}
```

This starts out looking fairly general, but makes the code that uses it be all about manipulating a database; what it actually does gets lost in all of the code that implements the logistics of that. And over time, it tends to become more and more implementation-specific, until you can't easily replace the implementation anymore (even if it's only for testing). It also becomes hard to change the code in the two components independently, because changes propagate around, sometimes in surprising ways.

Alternatively, you could create smaller, more focused repository interfaces to suit the specific needs of particular components in your system, with methods that have names that represent *meaningful usage scenarios* of the owning component, and deal in and return domain-specific types:

```java
// Suppose it's a music app, and that the owning component 
// is concerned with searching for playlists. It has nothing 
// to do with creating them, nothing to do with updating or 
// deleting them, it just implements searching 
// (remember the Single Responsibility Principle & 
// the Single Responsibility Principle)

public interface PlaylistRepository {
    Iterable<Playlist> getAll();
    Iterable<Playlist> findByName(String name);
    Iterable<Playlist> findByTag(String tag);
    Iterable<Playlist> findBySong(Song song);
    Iterable<Playlist> findByAuthor(Author song);
}
```

This is more high-level and makes your search code more readable (this interface is now more of a true abstraction), and you can evolve the two components independently, but there's a catch. Once your code is in the wild, and you have multiple implementations, it's not going to be easy to add new methods to (or remove methods from) this interface - so you have to come up with an interface that changes less often compared to the owning component and the implementing component. So, there are always tradeoffs. If the interface is stable, it's going to be easier to maintain and evolve the code. However, if your application is modular, with focused components, aligned with the needs of the business/domain, you might be able to support new functionality by introducing new components and possibly composing them together (so instead of changing the existing interface, you might add a separate `AdvancedSearchComponent(QueryablePlaylistRepository repo)`, with a repository that supports advanced querying).

P.S. My answer was based around the specific concern you mentioned, but note that you don't always have to assign the ownership of the interface in this same way. If it's Object B that owns the interface, than it's a "provided interface" that lets the outside world interact with Object B, while allowing you to restructure the code behind that boundary. (E.g., if your Object B is becoming a bloated God class, you can split it into multiple smaller classes, with one of them acting as a thin facade that just implements the interface and coordinates how these other objects interact. Then you can independently tweak those objects, improve the implementation, or simplify the design, then realize some of them aren't needed and remove them, and so on.)